# sql insert query with select

Tags: mysql, select, insert

Given this table where both `reviewid` and `prankid` are auto increment.

```
CREATE TABLE Review
(
reviewId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
prankId INT NOT NULL,
rating INT,
comment VARCHAR(1056) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(reviewId),
FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES User(email),
FOREIGN KEY (prankId) REFERENCES Prank(prankId)
);
```

Would this insert statement correctly insert values into all of the attributes in review table.

```
INSERT INTO Review (email, prankId) SELECT email, prankId from User;
INSERT INTO Review (rating, comment) VALUES(‘5’,’amazing!’);
INSERT INTO Review (rating, comment) VALUES(‘5’,’brilliant!’);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want this:

```
INSERT INTO Review (email, prankId, rating, comment)
    SELECT email, prankId, 'S', 'amazing!'
    from User;

INSERT INTO Review (email, prankId, rating, comment)
    SELECT email, prankId, 'S', 'brilliant'
    from User;
```

In your version, the last two `insert`s will fail because `email` and `prankid` are `NULL`.  Remember, `insert` adds new rows into the table.  It doesn't modify existing rows.